# How can I specify a devcontainer feature more than once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm building a custom devcontainers file and need to add a couple of homebrew packages. In the [features](https://containers.dev/features) list, there's a `homebrew-package` that
does the job. The only problem is, this only accepts one `package` (there's a similar `pipx-package` feature which has the same format/problem).

How can I specify this feature multiple times so that I can install multiple homebrew packages? The best I can think of is repeating the declaration, but that doesn't work for obvious reasons.

```json
{
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/homebrew-package:1": {
      "package": "detect-secrets"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/homebrew-package:1": {
      "package": "markdownlint-cli"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - this cannot be done.

If you want to do this, you need to create a local custom feature. This can be solved fairly elegantly by calling the package via a bash script.

As an example, the [neovim-homebrew package demonstrates](https://github.com/devcontainers-contrib/features/blob/a89e281a4e977798551f1936efcb0c9ddf553941/src/neovim-homebrew/dependencies.sh#L65,L69) how to call a package from another package via the [Dev Containers CLI](https://github.com/devcontainers-contrib/cli)